# Overflow-y auto not working in this case

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem with overflow-y: auto. I got a div working just how I want it: with a header and a footer capping the content at its max height and staying visible at the top and bottom respectively when shrinking the viewport, the only thing I can't get to work is the scrollbar in the content in the middle. I can get a div to scroll but not with this header/footer behaviour. Please help.

Here's the code. Sorry if it's not clean enough:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #3d5266;
  margin: 12px;
  background: lightblue;
}
#container {
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 24px);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin: auto;
}
header, footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 5;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding: 0 8px 0 8px;    
}
header {
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;  
}
footer {
  bottom: 0;  
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px; 
}
section {
  margin: 40px 0;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    header text
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="content">

      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>

    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    footer text
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want it to behave??

Comment: I want the footer to come right after the content when content is short and when it's long I want the scrollbar only over the .content div, with the header and footer fully visible and static against the top and bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must give perfect height to the content element in order for the scroll to work.

`height: calc(100vh - 24px - 40px - 40px);`

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #3d5266;
  margin: 12px;
  background: lightblue;
}
#container {
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 24px);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin: auto;
}
header, footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 5;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding: 0 8px 0 8px;    
}
header {
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;  
}
footer {
  bottom: 0;  
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px; 
}
section {
  margin: 40px 0;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 24px - 40px - 40px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    header text
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="content">

      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      aaaabla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>
      bla<br>

    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    footer text
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: It works in that it scrolls but now the container doesn't adjust to shorter content, and I would like to keep that flexible.

Comment: use `max-height` instead.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I accepted the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Well since the entire component is within the div with id = "container" and you gave the container div overflow: hidden in the css, so it basically overrides the css property given to content

in your css #container
change it to

```
  overflow-y: scroll ;
  overflow-x: hidden ;
```

Comment: But I want a scrollbar only on the content div and not over the whole container, so that the header and footer are always fully visible.